# Why do you have to 'import' Python Standard Library functions?

Tags: python, language-design, python-import

I'm new to Python coding and I'm coming from a PHP background. I'm curious why you have to 'import' functions at the top of you python script. In PHP you can simply use the function such as:

```
sleep(10);
```

The above would cause the script to sleep for 10 seconds. However, to do the same thing in python, it seems I have to import the 'time' functionality:

```
import time
time.sleep(10)
```

My question is: why is this necessary? If these extra functions are part of python already, why does python have to specifically load them? In PHP, if a module is missing, the script fails. I have to install the module globally and then it's usable like normal.

Is there an advantage to python's approach?

Comment: Imagine the fun if every name was visible at the same time.

Comment: Corollary: are there downsides to PHP's approach?

Comment: This is potentially a really interesting question, and is clearly and intelligently written, but I think it's outside the scope of StackOverflow; you're not asking for help solving a problem, nor asking for objective factual detail about how a language feature works, but rather asking a partially-subjective question about the design of someone else's language. I think it would, however, be a great and on-topic question for programmers.stackexchange.com. I'm going to flag this for mod attention and ask that it be migrated there.

Comment: Update: mods declined my flag. No reasoning given.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Most likely the Programmers moderators felt the question would not be a good fit there either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, several. It means that there is less to compile and run by default. Your program will load faster, because it only knows about the parts of Python that it actually needs.

It keeps the global namespace clean, and allows functionality to be grouped logically into modules. Different modules can have identically-named functions without clashes (a file and socket class would probably both have open and close functions, for example).

Comment: Ah, so it keeps Python, as a whole, less bloated cause it doesn't have all the modules loaded everytime. That makes sense, and DOES sound like an advantage. Thanks!

Comment: How can I know if a given function is part of the standard library or outside package?

Comment: And it ensures that multiple libraries can simultaneously implement similar yet incompatible functionality with similar yet incompatible names.

Answer (score 4):

Well, what if you want to use both library `A` and library `B` with a function called `f`? In Python this is super easy: you import both of these modules, and then you qualify correct `f`s name with it's module, e.g. `A.f()`

This leads to the first advantage: namespaces (as a solution for name-clashing problem) and non-polluting global scope.

The second advantage is more flexible module system.

Answer (score 0):

But you don't need to import functions like "print()" or "input()".
These functions are provided for you already.  The others are not necessarily needed
so they're located elsewhere, that's why you import modules containing functions that 
are not provided by default

Comment: Small addition: `print` is [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) and so you can reach it with `__builtins__.print` even if you overwrote `print` before.